# how do I interpret graph after scale_x_log10 in geom_density function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is a definitely pdf with under area = 1

[image]

but after scaling X axis by the code

```
#scale_x_log10() +
```

the graph changed like this.

after

[image]

I guess this is not a pdf , as under area >= 1

So, my question is what the y-axix means in after graph?

Thank you so much.

I did my best do guess

Comment: The 2nd graph cannot be interpreted like you seem to want, `f(log10(x))` does not integrate to unity and `y=f(log10(x))` does not give `y` a special meaning. The small differences between control and stimulus in the 1st graph are now more visible but still small. In your use case are such differences, between the tails and between the maxima, meaningful?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.